# Client doesn't find port on a different network

Tags: android, sockets, networking

I want to build a basic server socket and client program, which I have, and it works, but only over the same Wi-Fi network. The server is a program on my computer, and the client is an Android application. Many people suggest port forwarding, but I think I've already done that by going to

> Windows Firewall with Advanced Security >
>
> Inbound Rules >
>
> New Rule

and creating a new port for 44443 (TCP). The current IP address I am using on the client is my public IP Address (e.g. googling "What's my IP?"). It doesn't work either when I use the local 192.168.xxx.xxx. I don't have access to the router settings and login, if that is required. The phone (client) doesn't connect to the server (computer) over different networks. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a programming question, but more like a IP networking question. However, since you are trying to use phone's ISP cellular network, probably your ISP blocks most of the public ports like TCP 44443 on all user nodes despite you have opened a public port on your router side (your node). The only way to bypass ISP's blockage is to use tunneling approach like VPN or use unblocked public ports like TCP 443 or TCP 80

Comment: Is it possible for me to set the server socket port id to 443 or 80 in Java?

Comment: You can set your internal/private program's port to anything that your OS allows. In Linux, anything below 1024 is not allowed. But, the important part is your port forwarding on your router side to expose the public ports which will forward the data to your internal/private ports of your program. Yes, you can set public port TCP 80 or TCP 443 on your router to forward your internal/private port of your program which can also use the same port number or can use a different port number (depends on your router's port forwarding design).

Comment: OK thank you @eee for your help on my question. I'll see what I can do about my program using your tips.